# How to map a subdomain to a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Google App Engine project that consists of multiple modules, with each module serving as a microservice. Each module is located at the project's root level and has its own web.xml file.

I am familiar with how the servlet spec works and can map a servlet to a relative path:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>accounts</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myapp.accounts.DatastoreServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>accounts</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But if I use any domain in my browser that gets directed to my web app, the servlet above will be executed. What I really want is that the servlet only launches for the subdomain:

```
https://accounts.myapp.com
```

and not for some other domain like:

```
https://users.myapp.com
```

Is there a way to specify this in the web.xml file? According to the servlet 3.1 spec:

> The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to
>   the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>   http://host:port//. In this case the path info is ’/’
>   and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).

But this does not indicate any support for a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping to specific domains is not supported, but you can use `request.getServerName()` and return 404 if you don't like what it returns for the same effect.

Note that in `http` the server name is technically optional (the value is in the `Host` header). In practice it is always sent unless the server is accessed via the IP address (ie: URL `http://<ip address>`).

Comment: Actually, when using subdomains on the Google's App Engine, you don't concern yourself with IP addresses when it comes to https. This is because subdomains must use a --dot-- format instead of using the "." to separate the subdomain from the host. This allows GAE to create a single SSL certificate to cover all subdomains. As for the IP addresses, that is something the GAE handles transparently.

Comment: you are right - I didn't think of wildcard certificates - removed the https remark (it was semi-OT anyways)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your DNS with *.yourdomain.com and save the subdomains in your database once the request coming to the specific subdomain get the subdomain using `request.getServerName().split("\\.")[0]`
and check in DB and map the result as per the subdomain.
[image]

Comment: While it is possible to create a subdomain using a custom domain in the GAE, that still has no effect on how servlets are activated. I'm looking for some mechanism that causes GAE to map an incoming subdomain to a particular servlet. The solution I just came across is using a Dispatch file:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url but it isn't clear whether the servlet spec has it's own built-in support.

Comment: @AndroidDev: updated the mapping which I'm using in GAE, I used the wildcard *.domain.com then mapped by subdomain request.